# ActiveMQ 5.8 Http GET configuration or example

Tags: web-services, uri, activemq-classic, apache-camel, http-get

I've installed ActiveMQ 5.8 and have created some internal queues.
I then created camel routes to reroute messages from first queue(inbound.A) to other internal queues (B,A,D etc).

Now the next part is to configure ActiveMQ to recieve xmls from a webservice which posts messages to a http URL. I have tried to get some examples but none of the bundled demos are working.

I can see that there is nothing in the webapps/api/ folder. Even when o looked in the webapps-demo/demo folder I don't see any examples of how I can do this or something similar.

I have outlined that I need to :

1. First expose a url where the producer webservice can access it .Can this be simply done by updating the transport connector?

   `<transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
       <!--<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>-->
   </transportConnectors>`
2. Then I need to configure this endpoint so that messages posted to this URL reach my inbound.A queue.

Can someone suggest any examples i can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just need to post XML messages to an ActiveMQ queue, then just use [camel-jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) to expose an inbound HTTP endpoint and send the XML as text directly to the queue, like this...

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="InboundHTTPRoute">
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/inbound/"/>
        <inOnly uri="activemq:inboundQ?jmsMessageType=Text"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

otherwise, if you need to define an HTTP SOAP interface, use [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

Comment: Thanks @boday i also did a similar thing,  just exposed one of the queues through apache.